# Scanning and finding sensitive data in an Elasticsearch index in an efficient way

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

**What I have :** Elastic search database for full text search purposes.

**What my requirement is :** In a given elasticsearch index, I need to detect some sensitive data like iban no, credit card no, passport no, social security no, address etc. and report them to the client. There will be checkboxes as  input parameters. For instance, the client can select credit card no and passport no, then clicks detect button. After that,  the system will start scanning index, and reports documents which include credit card no and passport no. It is aimed to have more than 200 sensitive data types, and clients will be able to make multiple selections over these types.

**What I have done :** I have created a C# application and used Nest library for ES queries. In order to detect each sensitive data type, I have created regular expressions and some special validation rules in my C# app which works well for manually given input string.

In my C# app, I have created a match all query with scroll api. When the user clicks detect button, my app is iterating all the source records which returns from scroll api,and  for each record, the app is executing  sensitive data finder codes based on client's selection.

The problem here is searching all source records in the ES index, extracting sensitive datas and preparing report  as fast as possible with great amount of documents. I know ES is designed for full text search, not for scanning whole system and bringing data. However all data are in elasticsearch right now and I need to use this db to make detecting operation.

I am wondering if I can do this in a different and efficient way. Can this problem be solved with writing an elastic search plugin without a C# app? Or is there a better solution to scan the whole source data in ES index?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Passport number, other sensitive information detection algorithm should run once, during indexing time, or maybe asynchronously as a separate job that will update documents with flags representing the presence of sensitive information. Based on the flag the relevant documents can be searched.
2. Search time analysis in this case will be very costly and should be avoided.

Comment: Yes sensitive data types can be detected during index time. However let's say I have changed or improved credit card detector algorithm.  In this case I have to query all documents and execute the detector engine again. In addition, as time goes by, I can add other sensitive data types to the system. Although I can construct a flag mechanism, I will need to query and update whole index.